# How can I setup skeleton tracking using a Kinect and ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ros, skeleton-tracker, ubuntu, openi-tracker, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read about openni_tracker, but that doesn't work with Indigo, so, I'm struck. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214421/how-can-i-setup-skeleton-tracking-using-a-kinect-and-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04?/) by [ravit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23198/ravit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2015-10-29**:
Same here, please any help will be appreciated!

**Comment by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on 2017-01-06**:
hey buddy!!!!!!!! did u got any help ??? i also need to use this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not true that `openni_tracker` doesn't work on Indigo. What is true is that `openni_tracker` is not released as a debian package on Indigo i.e. as of right now, it can't be installed via `apt-get`. There have been some [recent issues](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_tracker/pull/8) with properly releasing the package.

Note that the [README](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_tracker/blob/hydro-devel/README.md) for the package mentions that in newer versions you will need to install the NITE package separately before using the package. So your general steps are going to involve

1. Downloading a NITE package and unzipping the archive
2. Running the `install.sh` script as root to install the package
3. Clone the `openni_tracker` repository into your ROS workspace `src/` directory
4. Run `catkin_make` to compile the package yourself.

If you run into compilation errors (ignore warnings about deprecated Xn functions), then you likely haven't installed the NITE package correctly. If `openni_tracker` builds, but it won't run for some reason, then you need to do some further debugging steps. Here are a few good resources:

- [Issue 9](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_tracker/issues/9) on the `openni_tracker` GH page has some nice debugging tips
- I wrote [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/109411/asus-xtion-problems-with-ubuntu-1204-running-ros-fuerte/#109831) a while ago that I often return to for advice

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Inder](https://answers.ros.org/users/25019/inder/) on 2015-11-13**:
I am currently trying to get openni_tracker to run. I just wanted to see what command is being used to run openni_tracker. I am trying to run it with `rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker` but this returns that it can't find an executable.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-11-13**:
That's the right command. Likely, either you don't have your environment/workspace setup correctly (have you sourced the setup.bash?), or you haven't successfully built the `openni_tracker` package with `catkin_make`.

**Comment by [G212](https://answers.ros.org/users/25216/g212/) on 2015-12-17**:
Gracias!!!!!! Thanks!!!!!!!

**Comment by [liyan9562](https://answers.ros.org/users/26186/liyan9562/) on 2016-03-06**:
hi, I get the same problem,it says it is not executable. So have you worked it our?

**Comment by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on 2017-01-06**:
hi... i also want to use openni_tracker feature with ros indigo... but while running : rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker, it says Can't create any node of the requested type!.... please help